# Linking a massive amount of string keys to classes using a static dictionary-like class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, dynamic, dictionary

Currently, I have two classes MC_Dictionnary_Bad, and MC_Dictionnary_Good, initialized like so:

```
package classes
{
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public dynamic class MC_Dictionnary_Bad extends Dictionary
    {
        public function Custom_Dictionary()
        {
            this["monster,0,0,0"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Red";
            this["monster,0,0,1"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Blue";
            this["monster,0,0,2"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Yellow";
            this["monster,0,0,3"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Dark";
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

They are initialized during loading, and are saved like so during the entire game.

I need to link a name and three indexes to class names, so I can create the appropriate class when needed, given user input.

However, I don't want to use a dynamic class.

Is there a clean way not to use a dynamic class here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to extend [`Dictionary`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) for this model - simply have two dictionaries in a class:

```
package {
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public final class Game {

        protected var MC_Dictionnary_Bad:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        protected var MC_Dictionnary_Good:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

        public function Game() {
            initialize();
        }

        protected function initialize():void {
            MC_Dictionnary_Bad["monster,0,0,0"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Red";
            MC_Dictionnary_Bad["monster,0,0,1"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Blue";
            MC_Dictionnary_Bad["monster,0,0,2"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Yellow";
            MC_Dictionnary_Bad["monster,0,0,3"] = "Monster_Light_Swanp_Dark";
        }
    }
}
```

If your keys are always strings, this could be defined as [`JSON`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) which would also enable easy data loading.  Instead of embedding the object in your app, it could be loaded from a url and [parsed](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse()).

```
package {

    public final class Game {

        protected var monsters:Object = {
                "good": {
                    "monster": {
                        0: {
                            0: {
                                0: "Monster_Light_Swanp_Red",
                                1: "Monster_Light_Swanp_Blue",
                                2: "Monster_Light_Swanp_Yellow",
                                3: "Monster_Light_Swanp_Dark"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "bad": {
                /* etc... */
                }
            };

        public function Game() {
            // Example accessor:
            trace(monsters["good"]["monster"][0][0][1]);
        }
    }
}
```